# Are favorited questions preserved during migration?

Tags: support, migration, bookmarks

On [Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/), I have starred the question *[What is the best way to download a list of stack exchange questions for offline browsing?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12495/358766)*.

In the comments, the author has requested that their question be migrated from Meta Super User to Meta Stack Exchange.

**If a question is migrated, will my account still list the question as favorited, or will I need to wait until the question has been migrated to re-star it?**

Comment: It has been migrated so now you can answer your own question :)

Comment: @DavidPostill As the duplicate suggested, I did indeed need to refavorite the question.